# eloquent json where empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, eloquent

The query I need to do is something like this

```
select `id` ,
json_extract(meta,"$.A") as a,
json_extract(meta,"$.B") as b
 from `C` 
where json_unquote(json_extract(meta, '$."A"'))>
json_unquote(json_extract(meta,'$.B'))
```

running it on workbrench gives me 2 results

```
Results
ID   a
414 2000    1500
426 2000    1500
```

But when I pass it to the orm of eloquent, the result is empty

```
DB::table('C')->select('meta->A')->
        where('meta->A','>',"json_unquote(json_extract(meta,'$.B'))")->get();
```

Debugging the library, I see that within the PDO functions, somehow it is not properly binding the parameters

```
array:9 [
  "select" => []
  "from" => []
  "join" => []
  "where" => array:1 [
    0 => "json_unquote(json_extract(meta,'$.B'))"
  ]
  "groupBy" => []
  "having" => []
  "order" => []
  "union" => []
  "unionOrder" => []
]


array:1 [
  0 => "json_unquote(json_extract(meta,'$.B'))"
]
"statement bind value"
PDOStatement {#3745
  +queryString: "select json_unquote(json_extract(`meta`, '$."A"')) from `C` where json_unquote(json_extract(`meta`, '$."A"')) > ?"
}
```

How could I modify it to do exactly the query I need? , I tried using whereRaw, but I have the same problem with binding

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that your raw-query is not using the built-in functions of mysql, since actually not that raw (still being built).

You could either make the query as actually raw by removing the builder in total or even better, use the JSON capabilities in laravel itself.

[Laravel Queries - JSON where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses)

Something along the lines of:

```php
DB::table('C')->select('meta->A')
    ->whereJsonContains('meta->A', '$.B')
    ->get();
```

Comment: jsoncontains only serves to see if B is in A, but I want to compare A> B or A<B ,etc,